# polyfit quadratic plot in python

Tags: python, quadratic

I am trying to plot a quadratic equation `y = a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*(x**2)` in python where points `(x,y)` are given. I have put the points into an array, but I'm having troubles with the plot. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong with my code?

```py
    data = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,8],[3,8]])
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    a_0, a_1, a_2 = np. polyfit(x, y,z, 1)
```

The last line returns error

> not enough values to          unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: See [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) for the return values.

Comment: How do you define `z`?

Comment: its not defined, I just put that there thinking it would fix the error, but it did not help

Comment: i would like to polyfit the quadtratic : y = a_0 + a_1*x + a_2*(x**2)

Answer (score 3):

Your data

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,8],[3,8]])
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
```

you can fit with quadratic polynomial using [numpy.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) returning just a single output argument

```
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
z
```

```
array([-0.25,  3.85, -0.65])
```

You can then assign the coefficients into a polynomial `p` in order to apply the polynomial to some values

```py
p = np.poly1d(z)
p(x)
```

```
array([-0.65,  2.95,  6.05,  8.65])
```

Comment: Thank ou very much

Comment: @jojo You may upvote useful answer(s) and accept the answer you find correct and most suitable one.